# I try to display xChart in my application end with Cannot call invokeAndWait

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have example code from the main repo of xChart [git repo](https://github.com/knowm/XChart)

I am trying to show the chart in my app but I end with this error.

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Cannot call invokeAndWait from the event dispatcher thread

Here is my code:

```
public class BarCharts extends JFrame{
public static CategoryChart chart;


public BarCharts() {
    createChart();

}

public void createChart() {
    chart = new CategoryChart(300,400, Styler.ChartTheme.XChart);
    chart = new CategoryChartBuilder().width(800).height(600).title("Score Histogram").xAxisTitle("Score").yAxisTitle("Number").build();
    chart.getStyler().setLegendPosition(Styler.LegendPosition.InsideNW);
    chart.getStyler().setHasAnnotations(true);
    // Series
    chart.addSeries("test 2", Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9,10,11,12}), Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{4, 5, 9, 6, 5, 20, 10, 120, null,null,null,null, null}));

    new SwingWrapper<CategoryChart>(chart).displayChart();
}
```

When I click a button is suppose to open the swingwrapper JFrame with the chart but its end with error.What I am missing here?

This is example code from guide:
[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64M5p.png)

Comment: Clicking the button executes some code on the event dispatch thread, and this code contains SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait, which causes the exception. Move the code to a new thread.

Comment: How to do that I mean i need to work in my application

Comment: There is some code for the button you have not shown here. Maybe an ActionListener or an Action. This code (or a part of it) should be moved to a new thread.

Comment: Ok thank you I found a solution from the library

Answer (score 0):

You only need to show your chart in a new thread, as suggested by [tniessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15181791/tniessen) in the comments.

Below code snippet that worked for me:

```java
new Thread(() -> {
    JFrame frame = new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        () -> frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
    );
}).start();
```

This also avoids closing the entire swing application when you close the chart.